# Adjust counter in Quarto RevealJS slides

Tags: r, pandoc, reveal.js, quarto

I am using `quarto` to create a set of slides. For each chapter, I am creating a separate document. Within each chapter, I would like to use the number of the chapter (i.e. the document) as first level counter, and then the section as second level.

As an example, the following code

First document:

```
# First part of the document

This should be part 1.1

## First section/slide

This should be numbered as 1.1.1

# Second part of the document

This should part 1.2

## First section/slide of the second part

This ould be numbered as 1.2.1
```

For the second document, would then like to have:

```
# First part of the document

This should be part 2.1

## First section/slide

This should be numbered as 2.1.1

# Second part of the document

This should part 2.2

## First section/slide of the second part

This ould be numbered as 2.2.1
```

And so on...

I already tried to adjust `number-offset` or `shift-heading-level-by` but that does not create the desired effect.